# Getting NSRangeException Beyond Bounds Crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, crash, nsrange

I have this code that is crashing with error `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSArray objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'`

at this line:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyObject *myCode = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

I don't see whats wrong here, it is pulling the data from a fetch.

Comment: You don't think there's something wrong if you're trying to access the first element of an empty array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is right in your post `'reason: ' ... index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'`. Your `self.fetchedResultsController` is empty now you need to investigate why.

Note: Whenever you modify the underlying data for a table view you need to update the changes by either calling `-[UITableView reloadData];` or the `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` methods then adding or removing the correct index paths.

Comment: The crash happens when I click the x (clear) icon in the UISearchBar after already searching.  The searching works fine, just crashes when I clear it by pressing the x.

Comment: Ok so thats a start. When you clear it you probably need to reload the tableView that contains the results you can click on that way the table will be empty and the user can not select a row outside of the bounds of the data.

Comment: When I click the text in the UISearchBar, then click the x, it works fine.  It only crashes when I click the X and not the text itself.

Comment: Thanks, I have all the code related to the search functions here in this question halfway through, I can't seem to see anything wrong as I am reloading the table. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338379/getting-exc-bad-access-crash-with-uisearchbar-method

Comment: Try implementing the [`UITextFieldDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) method `-(BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField*)textField` and try clearing your data, reloading the table, and then return YES.

Comment: I added this but no luck with it: `-(BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField*)textField
{
    mySearchBar.text = @"";
 [mySearchBar resignFirstResponder];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    return YES;}`  I don't understand why `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is even being called when I click the x button.

Comment: Make sure you clear your fetched results. Also start adding logs so you can see what the count is your returning for your tableview etc until you find out where the discrepancy is.